# Pointers in C (Function call address)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f2(){}

void f1(){
    int b=3,c=7;
    c=b+c;
    f2();
    printf("B\n");
}

int main (void) {
    int a=3;
    a=a+1;
    f1();
    printf("A\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Write a code inside the f2 function which will change the control of the above C program. As per the above code, the control goes from main function to f1 function, f1 to f2 and thenreturn back again from f2 to f1 and f1 to main. But, you need to write some code only in function f2, which will move your control direct from f2 to main, so that output will come only “A” rather than “BA”. F1 function cannot be called more than once during the execution. You cannot modify f1 and main function

I tried writing something along the lines of

```
void f2(){
   void (*a)(void)=&f2;
   a=a+116;
   (*a)();
}
```

However, it does not work.

Comment: So you want to modify the stack so that when `f2` returns it will return directly to `main`, not to `f1`? Then you need to know the compilers stack-frame in great detail, together with the ABI of the compiler and OS.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Invisible nonlocal transfer makes code extremely hard to read or reason about. Anybody studying the function `f1()` in isolation will assume that after calling `f2()`, it will print `B`.

Comment: Are you the same user as the one who posted the linked duplicate, or taking the same class?